# Terraform dependency problem between local_file and provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Rabbitmq terraform [provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/rabbitmq/index.html#cacert_file) support `cacert_file` as argument, a file path to a custom CA. My custom CA is stored in AWS ssm parameters. I need to fetch it, put it into a file and use the path to the file value for `cacert_file` .

So, first I fetch the value :

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "rabbitmq_cacert_file" {
  name = "/shared/${var.metaenv}/rabbitmq/ca"
}
```

Then, I use this value to create a temporary file :

```
resource "local_file" "rabbitmq_ca" {
  content  = data.aws_ssm_parameter.rabbitmq_cacert_file.value
  filename = "${path.module}/rabbitmq_cacert_file"
}
```

and, finally, I use this file in my provider :

```
provider "rabbitmq" {

  endpoint        = "https://myhost:8443"
  username        = myuser
  password        = mypass

  cacert_file     = local_file.rabbitmq_ca.filename
}
```

but I have a problem creating the exection plan :

```
Error: open ./rabbitmq_cacert_file: no such file or directory
  on main.tf line 28, in provider "rabbitmq":
  28: provider "rabbitmq" {
```

I think it's a dependency problem : the file is not yet created when the configuration of the provider tries to read it.

As it's not possible to add a [dependency on provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2430), is there a way to solve my problem ?

Comment: If `local_file.rabbitmq_ca.filename` was an exported attribute, then there would be an implicit dependency here. Unfortunately, it is an argument to the resource. This should only be an issue for the initial apply, correct? Workaround here is to probably `target` the `rabbitmq_ca` resource before a full plan and apply, which is not super great, but would work for you.

Comment: `target` the resource is possible indeed but not adapted in my case as the terraform flow is part of CI/CD pipelines and not every use rabbitmq provider. Anyway, thanks for the idea.